# Jenkins - create a tar.gz from various ear and deliver it on a distant server

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, server, archive

I have a maven build which produces a *target/myModule.ear* for each module it builds.

I want to create a Jenkins job which :

**1) Build the project with a "mvn clean install"**

**2) Archive all the ear into a tar.gz**

**3) Deliver this tar.gz on a distant server**

I am very new to Jenkins so I don't know how to do 2) and 3). The only solution I can come up with is to create a script, but if I do that there is no point in using Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a parent project which has a war/jar and an ear project to wrap the war, then a distribution project to assemble the tar.gz.

parent looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
        <myproject.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</myproject.version>
  </properties>

  <name>ear-example</name>
  <modules>
    <module>example-ear</module>
    <module>example-war</module>
    <module>distribution</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

ear project has dependency to the war project and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>example-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-war</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
                <modules>
                        <webModule>
                                <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
                                <artifactId>example-war</artifactId>
                                <contextRoot>/appname</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The distribution project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Distribution</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-ear</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>ear</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>distro-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The assembly.xml which builds the zip looks like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>modules/maven-assembly-plugin</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

The deployment you will have to do yourself

Comment: Thank you I will try to do that !

Comment: I did just like you said and it works like a charm. Thank you.