# Maven is not building sibling dependencies in multi-model project

Tags: java, maven, build, multi-module

I have a multi-module project, in root POM I have:

```
<modules>
    <module>shared-lib1</module>
    <module>shared-lib2</module>
    <module>main-app</module>
</modules>
```

In `main-app` module I have listed my libraries like that:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The general build command is `mvn deploy -pl <changedList> -am -amd`

When my Jenkins automation detects change on push to branch, it analyses which files where changed from which module. So, for instance only `shared-lib1` is changed.

In that case the command will be `mvn deploy -pl shared-lib1 -am -amd`, which will put `main-app` into reactor list of projects to build due to `-amd` option.

However, it won't pick up `shared-lib2` and `main-app` will fail to build.

Is there any option to build the tree properly, so basically enable `-am` option for all the modules discovered by `-amd`?

UPD: `${project.version}` is getting updated each time as contains SHA of commit

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072533/jenkins-create-a-tar-gz-from-various-ear-and-deliver-it-on-a-distant-server/47073111#47073111) shows you how to do a multi module project, I suspect you have group or version, or not parent in your child projects.

Comment: all modules have artifactId set, module version matches parent version, their parent set to root project? is there anything else to check?

Comment: don't put version and group in the children, look at the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody answered this: this is expected behavior of Maven and how it builds the graph of modules. I tried to create my own graph builder, which should have been converted into the Maven builder, but I've moved from this activity long time ago:

https://gist.github.com/vladfau/eb34e4f3892d0207e399a0f1f84f83ff

This was written for Jenkins Pipeline, so has some CPS augmentations. Most notable method is `generateFullDependencyList`